# ValueError: Data type datetime64[ns] not understood. Please report an error to the developers

Tags: python, datetime64

I'm trying to convert a pandas df using df.to_stata. In the process I'm getting an error:

> ValueError: Data type datetime64[ns] not understood. Please report an error to the developers

A generalized version of the script is:

```
df.to_stata('myfile.dta')
```

For reference, I'm using stacked panel data in the form of:

```
Date          id     var
2017-01-01    A      5
2017-01-02    A      3
2017-01-03    A      4
2017-01-01    B      2
2017-01-02    B      -4
2017-01-03    B      1
2017-01-01    C      -2
2017-01-02    C      0
2017-01-03    C      6
```

Also, when I try to rewrite the line as

```
df.to_stata('myfile.dta', convert_dates={'Date' : 'td' })
```

I get KeyError: 0

I've transferred to stata and csv many times in the past without issue, and my usual google-search has not led me to a solution.